# PHP OAuth 2.0 authorization API and .NET Resource API

Tags: php, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, bearer-token

So we have a custom built PHP authorization Server that uses OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens and several resource APIs built in PHP. these are on different machines.

Now we want to develop .NET APIs also, but use the bearer tokens from the existing authorization server, all I have found are examples where both the auth server and the resource API are built in .NET, which talks about having the same machine key for decryption..

e.g.
http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: That's not a question we can answer. You're talking about two different systems built on different technology stacks. It makes no sense to change the stack and build the same thing again. The whole point of an API is that can be used by any client so the stack used to build it is irrelevant,.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu: I am not looking to change the stack and build the same thing again. I am looking to utilize the existing authorization server (built in PHP) for the resource API (building in .NET)... the only examples I have found are of both the auth server and the resource server in .NET..

Comment: you're not going to be able to do this, unless you manage to build a system which builds tokens in the same way in PHP as it does in dot net. The article you linked makes use of identity Server, so your custom PHP system will have to match those tokens exactly.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit clearer what you're trying to do so let's see if we can work out a solution.

Your problem is that you have an Authorization Server built in PHP which creates your tokens. You want to build a Resource Server in Dot Net, using something like Identity Server, which can makes use of these tokens.

I would start at looking how Identity Server generates those tokens. You're going to have to match that method in your PHP Authorization Server. I would build a dot net Authorization and Resource Server, get that working first. Once you get that working you then have two different Authorization Servers and now your goal is to make their tokens be exactly the same. if you can pull this off, problem solved.

This approach will more than likely take you a long time and you will have to build an Authorization Server in Dot Net anyway.

Taking a step back however, this, of course makes no sense and it's only going to create issues for you or whoever comes after you. If you manage to pull this off you will now have 2 things, written one in PHP, one in dot net and that's a recipe for disaster, from a maintenance and future development point of view.

You're better off choosing one stack and building both Authorization and Resource server with the same stack. So, either build your Resource Server in PHP or ditch the PHP Authorization server and build both in dot net.

Don't mix the stacks for this basically.

**** added after comments ****

just to be clear, yes oauth2 is a standard and it gives you an idea of what steps to follow and how to create your requests.

The standard doesn't tell you how to build everything, it gives you a high level overview. The authentication itself can use different mechanisms built on top of the same standard. Hope this clarifies everything,

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I thought the whole point of OAuth was to create a universal standard for authentication, regardless of the platform. The same way that social media authentication (fb, twitter, etc) can be implemented in both PHP and .NET services...

Comment: you don't generate a token on facebook and then you go and use it on google which is essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: added clarification to the main answer

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.. Our OAuth server issues a token from one endpoint, then another endpoint validates that token. So the resource server would need to call the validate endpoint manually, before allowing access to resources. I just don't know how to do this in Web API.